# What happens when TCP Sequence Number is incorrect?

Tags: tcp

Let's assume that A is connected to B, and A has received 100 bytes until now. So, the next packet he will receive should have a SEQ number of 100 or a little more if the packets don't reach A in order.

What happens if he receives a significantly different value, for example, 800?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Queue the traffic waiting for the rest of the traffic to arrive.  If that traffic doesn't appear within some hold-off period, it will re-ACK the last segment it received.  This is all *well documented* TCP processing. (read: use any search engine, or visit a book store.)

Comment: nice answer ricky

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't find the answer despite using a search engine, most results explain how it works, not what happens in special situations like this.

Comment: It's not a special situation. It's an integral part of the protocol -- reliable, error free, *in order* traffic delivery. 'tho I'll agree it's faster to ask someone who knows rather than research it yourself.

Comment: IMHO it's important to add that this only happens when the received SEQ falls within the receive window, otherwise the segment is dropped. Also, if both A and B support SACK (selective ACK) then instead of saying "I'm waiting for 100", A can also tell B "I'm waiting for 100 but I already have 800-2099" allowing B to just retransmit 100-799 instead of retransmitting everything from 100 on.